# Excel VBA macro to duplicate data if condition met

Tags: excel, vba

this is really advanced level of macro for me. If anyone could help, i really appreciate it!

1. I have Data as below.
   I want to write a macro that looks for the customerID, ex: if C2=C3, then i want it to look for either the row above or below using column D,  fill either up or down (ColumnA, ColumnB, and ColumnD) based on how the data came out. Because the data may come out like Row A2 will be emptied or Row A3 will be emptied but each customer can ONLY have 2 row maxed of data lines.

Comment: So in the case of your image (using "First Name" as cell A1), you want cells `A3,B3,D3` to be populated with `A2,B2,D2` because `C3` matches `C2` (and same for rows 4/5)? You say there will only be 2 rows for each customer but will these rows ALWAYS be next to each other or can they be separated? If they are always next to each other then it's easy but if they are not then a find element needs to be added. (oh just realised your same person I gave answer to yesterday)

Comment: Yes. Same person! Thanks so much for helping again. I am learning a lot from you! Yes, the two rows of data will be always next to each other. Except the names and order# will either be below or above. For example... Range A2-A3 is belong to me...however my name and order # can be either in the row A2. Or it can also be in A3 when I export the orders. This is where I stuck with the VBA code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer based on my comment being true. If not it can be updated afterwards.

I simply just took the basics from my answer I gave yesterday and modified it to meet the conditions of this question. You should be able to see the differences and how easily you can change it to do these sort of tasks.

```
Sub AddMissingInfo()

Dim ws As Worksheet, lrow As Long, arr, i As Long, j As Long

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1") 'Change to your sheet name
lrow = ws.Range("C" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Use customerID to find last row, change column if needed
arr = ws.Range("A2:D" & lrow).Value 'Populate the array, change columns/starting row if needed

For i = 1 To UBound(arr, 1) - 1 'Stop loop at line before last (alas the -1)
    If arr(i, 3) = arr(i + 1, 3) Then 'Check if customer ID matches the row below
        If arr(i, 1) = "" Then 'Checks first name
            If arr(i + 1, 1) <> "" Then arr(i, 1) = arr(i + 1, 1)
        Else
            If arr(i + 1, 1) = "" Then arr(i + 1, 1) = arr(i, 1)
        End If
        If arr(i, 2) = "" Then 'Checks last name
            If arr(i + 1, 2) <> "" Then arr(i, 2) = arr(i + 1, 2)
        Else
            If arr(i + 1, 2) = "" Then arr(i + 1, 2) = arr(i, 2)
        End If
        If arr(i, 4) = "" Then 'Checks Order#
            If arr(i + 1, 4) <> "" Then arr(i, 4) = arr(i + 1, 4)
        Else
            If arr(i + 1, 4) = "" Then arr(i + 1, 4) = arr(i, 4)
        End If

    End If
Next i

ws.Range("A2:D" & lrow).Value = arr 'Dump the info back to the range. Change columns/starting row if needed

End Sub
```

Comment: Simon, you are the man!  I very appreciate you helping me 2 days in a row! wish there is something i help you with but sadly i am a noob with excel stuff and i am trying to learn as much as i could. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad to help. VBA is surprisingly easy as it's a very basic language (alas called Visual Basic) so often things you would think would work do indeed, and if you get stuck intellisense can often help out by giving the recommendations (though Excels isn't the greatest. Something like Visual Studio on the other hand provides excellent intellisense). Just keep looking into it and you will pick it up fast.

Comment: @TheExcelMe Please do note though, that typically StackOverFlow isn't a free code writing service and the OP (you) need to show what you've attempted (code/formulas etc), what research you have done and what's not working about what you have tried. Since what you've asked for is fairly basic it's no real biggie but it's probably best to do a bit more research first as these kind of questions are incredibly common. So if you have something else soon, find a similar question, & try out the answer, modifying it to what you need, then come back here to get help with it if it's not quite working.